# Signals become undefined even though signal assignment is executed inside a VHDL process

Tags: vhdl, test-bench

Say I have this VHDL code-snippet, present in the architecture of an entity

```
p1 : process(resetn)
begin 
   if resetn'event and resetn = '0' then
      A <= '0';
      B <= '0';
   end if;
end process
```

And I have another process

```
p2 : process(clk)
begin
   if clk'event and clk = '1' then
      if some_expression then
         A <= '1';
      elsif some_other_expression then
         B <= '1';
      end if;
   end if;
end process
```

And the signals A and B are defined as follows:

```
signal A :  std_logic;
signal B :  std_logic;
```

What I'm seeing is that at the start of the simulation, my testbench is driving resetn from 1-> 0 -> 1 again (after certain ns)

However, these signals A and B are not assigned the value of '0' and remain 'U'  that too throughout the simulation (despite me ensuring that some_expression and some_other_expression both are hit)

Any idea why?

Comment: *"Any idea why?"* Yes you are driving the same signals from two processes. Please read up on VHDL, there is a standard language construct for asynchronous reset registers.

Comment: However, at the start of simulation, the some_expression and the some_other_expression don't hold true. Therefore, at any given point I only have one driver for the signals - is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: No, stick standard language construct. In the end you might get your code to simulate but then you have to start all over to get it through the synthesis tool.

Comment: @Oldfart Well I am not sure that the synthesis tool will refuse it. I mean if you have everything in the same process, it will work no ?

Comment: @AyoubBargach That is what the standard language construct for asynchronous reset registers has.